# Regex not displaying as expected in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have the following regex `\ssrc=(\"|\')([^\"|\']+)(\"|\')` which im using the scrape websites for images within the source code. The images i want are in the following format:

`<img src="http://www.asite.com/content/icon_clown.gif"`

`<img src='essays.gif'`

`<img src="monty-python-(1).bmp"`

`<img src="gchq-certified.jpg"`

My regex finds thems but displays them as:

`('"', 'http://www.asite.com/content/icon_clown.gif', '"')`

`("'", 'essays.gif', "'")`

`('"', 'monty-python-(1).bmp', '"')`

`('"', 'gchq-certified.jpg', '"')`

Im wanting them to display like this:

`http://www.asite.com/content/icon_clown.gif`

I need the regex to match all 4 image sources shown above.

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: You should add whole code sample - not just data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex contains 3 groupings, the `(..)`. You can get the middle one either by accessing the index 2 of your results (0 being all, 1 the first grouping etc.), or by using `( )` only around the middle part.

E.g. like:

```
x = "<img src=\"http://www.asite.com/content/icon_clown.gif\""

results = re.search("src=(\"|\')([^\"|\']+)(\"|\')",x)

print(results.group(2))
```

Output:

```
'http://www.asite.com/content/icon_clown.gif'
```

EDIT:

```
import re

x = "<img src=\"http://www.asite.com/content/icon_clown.gif\"" \
    "<img src=\'essays.gif\'" \
    "<img src=\"monty-python-(1).bmp\"" \
    "<img src=\"gchq-certified.jpg\""

results = re.findall("src=[\"|\']([^\"|\']+)[\"|\']",x)

print(results)
```

Output:

```
['http://www.asite.com/content/icon_clown.gif', 'essays.gif', 'monty-python-(1).bmp', 'gchq-certified.jpg']
```

Comment: Helpful, but not really what i'm looking for. Need the regex to display all 4 of the image sources.

Comment: @M.Manson Ahh, that's not clear from your question, in fact, your expected output in your question only includes one image.

Comment: @M.Manson See my edit. As I said, remove the groupings, if you want to match character X or Y use square brackets.